# What bootstrap components make "cancel" links look right?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to download a subset of Bootstrap that gives me alerts and modals. The main elements (the body of the alerts and the modals) appear correctly, but the "x" to cancel both the alerts and modals is showing up as misplaced and unstyled, respectively. For example:

http://imm.io/138VK

The only thing I've downloaded from http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/customize.html is the Alerts and Modals (plus their JS counterparts). What else am I missing? I've checked that there is no conflicting CSS.

For the alert, I can fix it by adding float: right; and then changing the pointer style (which shows a text entry cursor instead of a link), but I'd rather not do it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Bootstrap Customize page there's an option called **Close icon** under **Miscellaneous** section. Make sure you check this option before downloading your customized version of Twitter Bootstrap.